# How to get number of rows in a section in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am working on collection view and I want number of rows in previous section.
Is there any method which return number of row in section.
Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delegate method of the `UICollectionView dataSource` that you will need to implement in order to display the cells can be invoked manually.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Therefore you can call it using:

```
NSInteger numberOfRows = [self collectionView:self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:MAX(0, currentSection - 1)];
```

You do not want to get an out of bounds exception so I have capped it at 0*

**EDIT**

@holex raises a very good point - I was assuming you only had one column.

If you know the size of your items width you can do the following:

```
//Assuming a fixed width cell

NSInteger section = 0;
NSInteger totalItemsInSection = [self.feedCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];

UIEdgeInsets collectionViewInset = self.feedCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.sectionInset;
CGFloat collectionViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.feedCollectionView.frame) - collectionViewInset.left - collectionViewInset.right;
CGFloat cellWidth = [self.feedCollectionView.collectionViewLayout itemSize].width;
CGFloat cellSpacing = [self.feedCollectionView.collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacing];

NSInteger totalItemsInRow = floor((CGFloat)collectionViewWidth / (cellWidth + cellSpacing));
NSInteger numberOfRows = ceil((CGFloat)totalItemsInSection / totalItemsInRow);

NSLog(@"%@", @(numberOfRows));
```

We determine how many items will appear in a row, to be a able to determine the amount of rows in the section.

Comment: the number of _items_ and the number of _rows_ are not necessarily equal in a collection view. it seems you were not aware of this, because you are not presenting the number of _rows_ but the number of _items_ only – which is different.

Comment: @holex you are quite correct. Thank you for raising the error.

Answer (score 1):

There are two method in collectionview, notice that the method are not in the delegate of collectionview.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSections;
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

You can call [self.collectionView numberOfSections]; to find the sectionCount.

You can call [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:somesection]; to find the rows in some section.

Comment: okay, that looks a half-answer to getting the number of rows in a section... when do you finish it?

Comment: You should get currentSection like 'NSUInteger currentSection = xxx', if ((currentSection -1) < [self.collectionView numberOfSectins]) { NSUInteger previousRowCount = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:currectionSection - 1)];}

Comment: that gives the number of _items_ in a section, not the number of _rows_ in a section. a collection view can have more than one item in a row... so that is just a half solution, even though the original _model_ already has info about the number or sections and number of items in a section - because that populates the collection view, so it could have been read from there directly.

Comment: If your items have the same size, you could use itemCount/columnCount.Otherwise you should first get all item's indexPath. and using collectionviewlayout's class method finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath to get the frame of item, then figure out the row count. you should enumerate the frames add add row count when has different origin. by the way, how do you think the items are in the same row, if the size.height are not equal

Comment: so, why haven't you added to _that_ to your answer then originally? that was the OP's question.......